# Is it possible to get end game achievements using save manipulations?

Tags: achievements, bloodborne

I was wondering if this cheese was doable: Take a copy of your save game while only

> having ingested two or less One Third of Umbilical Cords.

Then go into the end game as accept Gehrman's offer thus ending the game and getting one achievement. After that, restore your save game and refuse Gehrman's offer thus ending the game and getting another achievement. Finally, restore the save game once again, and get to the true ending thus getting the final ending achievement.

Clearly, this is 100% pure rotting cheese. However, *is it possible to do this?*

Comment: For me, I just YouTube the endings...

Comment: Do we still need spoilers for Bloodborne? It is two years old and extremely popular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is certainly possible, I cheezed it the same way for the platinum. You can upload your save on your PS Plus account, make sure you deactivate auto-upload, then proceed to do as you suggested.

- Upload your save just before accessing the end-game area
- Get the first ending by choosing one of Gehrman's choices, download your save back on your PS4
- Get the second ending by choosing the other of Gehrman's choices, download your save back on your PS4
- Consume three umbilical cords, get the last ending, download your last save if you wish

Comment: Right, I'll edit my answer. But the save/upload thing still works.